# Why are emails sent to me bouncing with incorrect MX records error message?

Tags: mx-record, g-suite, email-bounces

I am having some very strange issues with email delivery to two different domains in separate google apps accounts.

- real domain name is liberatumsolutions.com and libsol.eu. The below error message is from an email to hello@liberatumsolutions.com
- 99% of emails sent to the domains work perfectly
- Aut a few partners have problems sending email to me - intermittently.
- Bounce messages always mentions MX servers like "waws-prod*****cloudapp.net"
- No such MX record exists for the domain.
- I have never hosted any kind of email or email config on Azure (to which  cloudapp.net belongs)

I have attached a screenshot of the MX records of one of the domains - it is only google apps mx records and no other MX records.

**Can you think of what might be the problem here?**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you sending this mail from? Via what software? What is in its logs? What is your real domain name?

Comment: Not providing us the actual domain name is going to make it impossible for us to give you any kind of insightful, useful, or helpful answer.

Comment: I assumed the question would be more general and overall helpful if this was kept more general and less specific to my domain. Anyway - point taken - and I have added the domain name to the question (liberatumsolutions.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a CNAME record on your @ as well as MX, and very likely SOA and NS records. This is NOT ALLOWED by DNS standards, specifically RFC1912, Section 2.4:

> 2.4 CNAME records
>
> A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data.  In
>   other words, if suzy.podunk.xx is an alias for sue.podunk.xx, you
>   can't also have an MX record for suzy.podunk.edu, or an A record, or
>   even a TXT record.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was not aware of that. Do you think that is the issue here, or are you pointing out another (possibly unrelated) error?

Comment: Just did a ping liberatumsolutions-com.azurewebsites.net (the cname in question) which actually responds from waws-prod-db3-085.cloudapp.net - the mx "server" mentioned in the error message. I will go remove that cname record and make it an a-record. Thanks! :)

Comment: So I wasn't sure if this is or is not related to your problems. Apparently it was :). And to help you out more (as you now have to take care of tracking the A record) some DNS providers have some kind of pseudorecord which can synthesize A/AAAA records from other domain name. Cloudns for example calls it ALIAS. Cloudflare has an option to flatten CNAME records at your root.  Have a look if you have such a record or option and give it a try.